# Springboot 3.2.0 not loading application context in JUnit code

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I have this JUnit code and it works without problems in Springboot 3.1.
But when I updgrade to Springboot 3.2.0, it fails, and it says it fails to load application context.
Can someone help me why this is happening?

Below is the code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(TestCreateService.class)
public class CreateServiceTest{
  @Autowired private TestCreateService testCreateService;
  @Autowired private TestRepository testRepository;

   ...

  @Test
  public void bulkGetOrCreateTest() throws InterruptedException {
       ...
      assertThat(executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
      assertThat(testRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
  }

}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] UploadTestRepositoryTest.find_with_inner_data » IllegalState ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [MergedContextConfiguration@589d106c testClass = co.domain.system.uploadfile.UploadTestRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [co.test.TestApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@23488e7a key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration,
```

Is there anything changed in Springboot 3.2.0?
Is the way of writing JUNIT test for repository changed?

Here is the error when I did a simple program:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@58a63629 testClass = com.example.helloworld.repository.UserRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@7de843ef key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@302c971f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@35841320, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@71075444, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@34be3d80, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@884bb438, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@4d15107f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@cd76d185], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testEntityManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'testEntityManager' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:802)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1878)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Had a similar issue with another annotation when migrating to 3.2.0. Try to remove those annotation one by one to pinpoint the error generating one. By the look of it I would bet on `@DataJpaTest`.
Would also be helpful if you could isolate a very simple class along with a `pom` which exhibits the issue.

Comment: I removed @DataJpaTest, I got a new error.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'co.domain.tell.TestRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

What seems to changed hhhhmmmmm

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a very simple project? A simple pom + a unit test should be enough. I need to know the version of all your dependencies.

Comment: I created a simple project having a repository unit test and using @DataJpaTest. And I was able to recreate the problem. The dependencies are: spring-boot-starter ver 3.2.0, spring-boot-starter-web ver 3.2.0, spring-boot-starter-test ver 3.2.0, jakarta.persistence-api ver 3.2.0-M1, spring-data-jpa ver 3.2.0, lombox ver 1.18.30...thats all my dependencies

Comment: I added the error on my initial post....

Comment: I dont understand the lease line of the error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: I think I got the point, the error `Fail to load application context` is just a front. Deep down there is an error that makes the loading of application context to fail. In my simple program, with the right dependencies, it works even using @DataTestJPA annotation

Comment: In my own investigation, the problem arises due to the upgrade of the hibernate-core library to version 6.3.1.Final when springboot was upgraded from 3.1.5 to 3.2.0. In this case, So this means we need to fix all errors related to this? Such a PITA... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was solved by adding a `columnDefinition` to an enum. I use MySQL as a database.

```
@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "type", length = 16, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(16)")
var type: EnumType = EnumType.FIRST_VALUE
```

Unfortunately, the error is not very clear, but that solved my issue. The error popped up once I started the application (but not within the tests).

Comment: is there something about it written in the release note of sprngboot 3.2.0?

Comment: In my own investigation, the problem arises due to the upgrade of the hibernate-core library to version 6.3.1.Final when springboot was upgraded from 3.1.5 to 3.2.0. In this case, So this means we need to fix all errors related to this?...Are there any other workaround?...

Answer (score 1):

My problem was resolved as followed: I migrated all the configurations from src/application.yaml into test/application.yaml and then I needed to make a test Bean @Primary and voila.